# I am receiving extra text from another plugin file in my ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am developing my own plugin for wordpress. In one scenario i am using ajax call to submit one of my form but i am receiving extra text which i researched turns out to be from another plugin file. The content of file is as follows.

```
<style>
.case td{
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
<?php

//code 

?>
```

This file is not part of my plugin. When i got response which was as follows

```
  <BR>
    <style>
    .case td{
        padding:5px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
    }
    </style>
```

Email sent successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This happens usually for one of three reasons:

1. Did you `exit` at the end of your `wp_ajax...` call? If not, WordPress continues to process. Add `exit` at the end of your `wp_ajax...` callback function.
2. It's coming from a poorly-coded plugin that is pushing that code to the browser way too early (often because it's not using hooks properly). Find the plugin, disable it, and find a better one to replace it.
3. You're not using `wp_ajax...` for your ajax call and rolled your own, possibly hooking it too late which means that other things are processing as well. Change your ajax call to use the `wp_ajax...` hook.

You didn't publish any of your code so I can't tell you which one or combination of these it is, but if you took care of #1 and #3, realize that there are a **ton** of terribly coded plugins out there (and some really great ones, but literally a **ton** of bad ones) and this is likely the issue.